# Font messes up alignment of numbers

Tags: html, css, fonts, typography

I'm using the Raleway font, but this font doesn't align numbers properly with letters.

You can see this in this snippet:

```css
    h1 {
      font-family: Raleway;
        font-size: 2rem;
        border-bottom: 1px solid $text-color;
        border-top: 1px solid $text-color;
        padding: 2rem 0;
    }
```

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<h1>5 Comments</h1>
```

Can I solve this easily? Or is this just a faulty font and should I chose another one?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the Typeface. Some Typefaces have their Xheight and baseline in numeric characters, different to letters. this is related to the design of the font and it is not an issue

Comment: Its font default property to renders numerals, Its not a faulty font.
For same alignment you can choose another font.

Comment: You must use another font.. this is how this font displays numbers http://typecast.com/preview/google/Raleway

Comment: okay, thanks for the fast responses!

Comment: you can solve this, but not easily.. you should consider using another font if this behaviour is irritating you..

Comment: You can wrap the number and string in two separate `<span>` elements and use `vertical-align: middle;` on the span holding the string to have it in line. But this is rather ugly and hard to maintain.

Comment: @NicoO: Are you sure, want to try and provide a working example of that?

Comment: @NicoO, This wont work, cz the "White space" Around any character is calculated with the X-height of this character.

Comment: Here is an example of a probably bad idea: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdvvWo

Comment: @NicoO: That doesn't really work, try changing the number to 1

Comment: @musefan you are correct. This won't work correctly- should have tested more cases. Thanks for the headups,

Comment: They’re called [old style figures](https://creativepro.com/typetalk-know-your-figures/).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## The Problem

This is part of the font itself and not something you can provide a quick fix for (unless you're dealing with very little text). If we look at [Google Font's page for the Raleway font](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Raleway), we'll see that numbers have different alignment to letters:

[image: Example]

If you don't want the numbers to be aligned like this, you're going to have to use a different font instead.

## A Fix

You can fix this by wrapping the numbers you wish to change the alignment of in a separate element and adjusting their `vertical-align` separately, but this is probably going to be more effort than its worth. I've given an example of this below:

```css
h1 {
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid $text-color;
  border-top: 1px solid $text-color;
  padding: 2rem 0;
}

.raised {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: 12%;
}
```

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<h1>
  <span class="raised">5</span>
  Comments
</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you for the very clear answer, I'm just going to look for a different font

Answer (score 39):

You can simply change with the help of CSS
add `font-feature-settings: 'lnum' 1;` to your css file

so your new css will be:

```
h1 {
        font-family: Raleway;
        font-size: 2rem;
        border-bottom: 1px solid $text-color;
        border-top: 1px solid $text-color;
        padding: 2rem 0;
        font-feature-settings: 'lnum' 1;
    }
```

Check out this too http://clagnut.com/sandbox/css3/

Comment: The only right answer for this question. I suppose, it should be marked as right.

Comment: Here is a good explanation why this CSS snippet is the solution: https://www.codesmite.com/article/fixing-raleway-and-similar-fonts-numerals

Answer (score 5):

2020 speaking

Depending on the font and the browser you can add

```
font-variant-numeric: lining-nums;
```

Source : https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font-variant-numeric/

Answer (score 2):

I created a version of Raleway with lining numerals as default to be used as **The Definitive Solution** for this problem. You can download the font files or just embed it into your HTML (using `<link>`) or CSS (using `@import`) with a single line of code, like you'd do with any other Google Font. Free, open source and available in all weights and styles:

https://h-ibaldo.github.io/Raleway_Fixed_Numerals/

Answer (score 2):

https://www.codesmite.com/article/fixing-raleway-and-similar-fonts-numerals

This article explains it all and gives de fully compatible css3 "solution".

This code do the magic:

```
.yourclass {
    -webkit-font-feature-settings: "lnum";
    -moz-font-feature-settings: "lnum";
    font-feature-settings: "lnum";
}
```

Comment: Thanks - adding this to the html element in Skeleton's normalize.css was the quickest way to fix the site.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on "the number case setting" feature of your font supports.

still you can do it by following [this](http://blog.amyworrall.com/post/46329875785/core-text-and-upper-case-numbers)

Further reading [UX stackexchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/54740/what-is-the-appeal-of-old-style-numbers-and-why-do-modern-fonts-still-include-th)

Answer (score 0):

I know you've posted this question a long time ago, but take a look at this property:

```
.class, #id, tag, * {
  font-variant-numeric: lining-nums;
  -moz-font-feature-settings:"lnum" 1; 
  -moz-font-feature-settings:"lnum=1"; 
  -ms-font-feature-settings:"lnum" 1; 
  -o-font-feature-settings:"lnum" 1; 
  -webkit-font-feature-settings:"lnum" 1; 
  font-feature-settings:"lnum" 1;
}
```

It forces all the numerals to be correctly aligned, so you can just apply this property to * in CSS and any text containing numbers will be a lot more readable.

Answer (score 0):

This code will work for Raleway, I have tested and got the result

`-webkit-font-feature-settings: "lnum"; -moz-font-feature-settings: "lnum"; font-feature-settings: "lnum":`